# Meteor user profile update

Tags: meteor

This Meteor client code is trying to update the current user profile with a new property `header` if it does not exist and asign to it a value from a variable `menuShortName`
The below code is crashing the app, it does not like `['header']` How can it be done? Thanks

I need to have both server and client be able to modify this value.

`Meteor.users.update({_id: userId},{$set: {profile['header']: menuShortName}});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is close. You must wrap nested properties in quotes:

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: userId}, {$set: {'profile.header': menuShortName}});
```